# Why can't I connect to a database the normal way with Qt?

Tags: c++, mysql, database, qt

I'm quite new to databases and trying to connect to a MySql database from my application using Qt.

The official documentation provides this example:

```
// I used QODBC driver because QMYSQL isn't available
QSqlDatabase db = QSqlDatabase::addDatabase("QMYSQL"); 
db.setHostName("bigblue");
db.setDatabaseName("flightdb");
db.setUserName("acarlson");
db.setPassword("1uTbSbAs");
bool ok = db.open();
```

But it doesn't work for me. The only way I managed to connect to my database is this:

```
QSqlDatabase db = QSqlDatabase::addDatabase("QODBC");
QString connectString = "Driver={MySQL ODBC 8.0 Unicode Driver};";
connectString.append("Server=127.0.0.1,3306;");   // IP,Port
connectString.append("Database=schema_name;");    // Schema
connectString.append("Uid=user_name;");           // User
connectString.append("Pwd=*****;");               // Password
connectString.append("MULTI_HOST=1;");
db.setDatabaseName(connectString);
```

It took me several days to find this solution, but now I wonder why the first one didn't work. Do you have any idea?

Also, I used MySql to create the tables and it brought another question: it might sound a bit stupid, but is there any difference between databases initialized by different DBMS? I don't know, maybe it has something to do with the driver I choose to read it...

Comment: Make sure you have `QMYSQL` driver available.

Comment: The Qt MYSQL driver is not available by default due to licensing issues of the MySQL library. Therefore you have to compile it by your own, use the QODBC driver or even better - use a database where Qt ships the plugin by default (e.g. PostgreSQL)